# Error Filling Between Curves in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to shade the region bounded by y=x^2, y=exp(-x), and the y-axis (in the first quadrant). This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-0.5,-.5) grid (3,4);
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw [->,samples=100,domain=0:2] plot(\x,{(\x)^2});
\draw [->,samples=100,domain=-0.5:2] plot(\x,{exp(-1*(\x))});
\draw [fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2] {[smooth,samples=100,domain=0:0.70346] plot(\x,{exp(-1*(\x))}) } -- {[smooth,samples=100,domain=0.70346:0] plot(\x,{(\x)^2})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting a strange line going from the point of intersection to the origin, also an error about not being able to parse this coordinate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your MWE does not compile for me: `Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.` Please correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong. You need to supply the plot options to the `plot` keyword, not to a group delimited by curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-0.5,-.5) grid (3,4);
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw [->,samples=100,domain=0:2] plot(\x,{(\x)^2});
\draw [->,samples=100,domain=-0.5:2] plot(\x,{exp(-1*(\x))});
\draw [fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2] plot [smooth,samples=100,domain=0:0.70346](\x,{exp(-1*(\x))}) -- plot [smooth,samples=100,domain=0.70346:0] (\x,{(\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Jake's answer is clearly the correct way to do this.  But here is a **hack** technique that may be useful for more complicated cases.  I first fill in the area under the exponential, which results in an area larger that we want. Then fill in `white` the area under the quadratic so that the fill appears only in the desired area. I draw the axis, and graphs *afterwards* so that they are on top.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% This overfills the desired area
\draw [draw=white,draw opacity=1,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2,
       smooth,samples=100,domain=0:0.70346] 
       plot(\x,{exp(-1*(\x))}) -- (0.70346,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 

% This "unfills" the appropriate area
\draw [draw=white,draw opacity=1,fill=white,fill opacity=1,
       smooth,samples=100,domain=0.70346:0] 
       plot(\x,{(\x)^2}) -- (0.70346,0) -- cycle;

\draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-0.5,-.5) grid (3,4);
\draw[thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[thick, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw [->,samples=100,thick,red,domain=0:2] plot(\x,{(\x)^2});
\draw [->,samples=100,thick,blue,domain=-0.5:2] plot(\x,{exp(-1*(\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```