# How to plot parabola in the selected segment using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot this: [image: area below parabola]

I know, that I can find intersections using TikZ (tried `\shade` but don't know how to plot parabola only in a segment), but I don't know how to plot this R figure, and S+T, and U+V. 
How can I plot this?
New detail: How [domain] works?

```
\tipc{[x=1cm,y=1cm]

  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{10}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{10}
  \draw[style=help lines, ystep=1, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
  (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw (-.25,-.25) node[auto] {0};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {$Q$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {$P$};
  \draw[red] (2,2) parabola (8,8) node[right,black] {$S$};
  \draw[blue] (8,2) parabola (2,8) node[left,black] {$D$};
  \draw[dashed]  (5,0) node[below] {$q_A$} -- (5,3.5);
  \draw[dashed] (3.72,-0.5) -- (3.72,2.5) -- (6.27,2.5) -- (6.27,-0.5);
  \draw[<->] (3.72,-0.5) node [below] {$q_s$}  -- ++(2.55,0) node [midway,below] {$Im$}
  node [below] {$q_d$};
  \begin{scope}
        \draw[color=red!30,domain=1.72:3]
            (5,3.5) parabola  (2,8)  |- (3.72,3.5);
    \end{scope}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess a nice tutorial for your purpose is [TikZ for economists](http://www.slideshare.net/kevingoulding/tikz-for-economists).

Comment: Just from looking at it, i would say this would be much easier to do with pgfplots (if you have mathematical expressions for the curves). You can handle the problem of getting the intersection with the sugestions from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/intersections-in-pgfplots

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understand your question correctly... Do you want to create exactly the plot you've shown above?

Comment: It would be great.

Comment: @Ptech can you provide exact coordinates or and approximation of the plot would be ok?

Comment: @Pouya i know intersection coordinates, and i want to fill area below parabola with color. I don't know how to plot this "triangle" (because this triangle is below parabola)

Comment: @Ptech I know you wanted the parabola but i couldn't manage it. I post an answer with quadratic function. I'm sure you can create you own quadratic which are very near to tikz parabola.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution. Please note that I have not used the parabola function of tikz because I failed to define the domain (not the end-points) and instead plotted two quadratic functions:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \def\xmin{0}
        \def\xmax{10}
        \def\ymin{0}
        \def\ymax{10}
        \draw[style=help lines, ystep=1, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid
        (\xmax,\ymax);

        \draw (-.25,-.25) node[auto] {0};
        \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmax,\ymin) node[right] {$Q$};
        \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- (\xmin,\ymax) node[above] {$P$};

        \def\intersectX{4.76}
        \def\intersectY{4.26}
        \def\QPX{4}
        \def\QPY{5}
        \draw[color=red] plot [domain=0:8] (\x,{((\x)^2)/10 +2)});
        \draw[color=blue] plot [domain=0:8] (\x,{((\x-14)^2)/20)});

        \fill[fill=pink,opacity=0.7] (0,\QPY) -- plot [domain=0:\QPY] (\x,{((\x-14)^2)/20)}) -- (\QPX,\QPY) -- cycle;
        \fill[fill=cyan,opacity=0.7] (0,\QPY) -- plot [domain=0:\QPX] (\x,{((\x)^2)/10 +2)}) -- (\QPX,\QPY) -- cycle;

        \draw [domain=\QPX:\intersectX] 
               plot(\x,{((\x-14)^2)/20)}) -- (\QPX,\QPY) -- (\QPX,\QPY) -- cycle; 

        \draw [fill=green,opacity=0.7,domain=\QPX:\intersectX] 
               plot(\x,{((\x)^2)/10 +2)}) -- (\QPX,\QPY) -- cycle;

        \draw[dashed]  (\intersectX,0) node[below] {$Q_1$} -- (\intersectX,\intersectY);
        \draw[dashed]  (0,\intersectY) node[below] {$P_1$} -- (\intersectX,\intersectY);
        \draw[dashed]  (0,\intersectY) node[below] {$P_1$} -- (\intersectX,\intersectY);
        \draw[dashed]  (\QPX,0) node[below] {$Q_2$} -- (\QPX,\QPY);
        \draw[dashed]  (0,\QPY) node[below] {$P_2$} -- (\QPX,\QPY);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

I used some help from [**this**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46187/error-filling-between-curves-in-tikz/46194#46194) answer as well.

Comment: This answer is great, I think, that i should get rid of parabola in tikz, and use plot instead (I had this question because parabola doesn't understand [domain])